# insert into SQLite the location every 5 minutes

Tags: java, android, android-studio, geolocation, android-sqlite

I want to insert into SQLite the location every 5 minutes, but the location is inserted every time it changes, I'm new with this, I know I have the insert inside the `onlocationchange`, but it's supposed to call every x time. I do not know what to do

```
public class GPS extends Service {
public static final int notify = 1000*60*5;  //interval between two services(Here Service run every 5 Minute)
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();   
private Timer mTimer = null;   

private LocationManager locationMangaer = null;
private LocationListener locationListener = null;
private static final String TAG = "Debug";
private Boolean flag = false;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    if (mTimer != null)
        mTimer.cancel();
    else {
        mTimer = new Timer();  
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplay(), 0, notify);  
    }

    locationMangaer = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

}


private Boolean displayGpsStatus() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
    boolean gpsStatus = Settings.Secure.isLocationProviderEnabled(contentResolver,LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (gpsStatus) {
        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    dbISMLock dbismlock = new dbISMLock(getBaseContext());
    final SQLiteDatabase db =dbismlock.getWritableDatabase();

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {



        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"fecha: "+ currentDateandTime +"Location changed : Lat: " + loc.getLatitude()+ " Lng: " + loc.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String longitude = "Longitude: " +loc.getLongitude();
        Log.v(TAG, longitude);
        String latitude = "Latitude: " +loc.getLatitude();
        Log.v(TAG, latitude);


        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String phoneID = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();

        //INSERT
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO GEOLOCATION( phoneId,Fecha,longitude, latitude) VALUES('"+phoneID+"','"+currentDateandTime+"','"+longitude+"','"+latitude+"')");
        Log.d("insertamos "," geolocation" );

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }




}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mTimer.cancel();    
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service is Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


class TimeDisplay extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Toast.makeText(GPS.this, coordenadas(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                flag = displayGpsStatus();
                if (flag) {

                    Log.v(TAG, "onClick");


                    locationListener = new MyLocationListener();


                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(GPS.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(GPS.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        return;
                    }
                    locationMangaer.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locationListener);


                } else {
                    Log.d("Gps Status!!", "Your GPS is: OFF");
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Probably you should write your own service which will do the work - save the location every 5 mins

Comment: M .. what it does is insert the location every time the location changes, but how do I get the latitude and longitude from the timer?

Comment: My problem is that I have what I need, but not in the time span that I want it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Service` to listen to location change in background and update it every 5 minutes. `onLocationchange()` is used to listen **manually** to changes. So you can ignore it for example and use the Service.

Comment: How do I do it? I'm supposed to use the linstener to get the location to change or not